# Why is MATLAB not hiding 2D trailing singleton dimension?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

A MATLAB array has an infinite number of trailing singleton dimension (theoretically).

So a `1x10` array is in fact a `1x10x1x1x1...` array. I suppose that MATLAB just hides the trailing singleton dimension.

You can observe this behaviour with this code snippet:

```
permute([1:10],[2,1,4,3])
```

MATLAB deals with permuting the 3rd and 4th dimension without any problem even if it's a 1D array.

**But why does MATLAB not hide the trailing singleton dimension in the 2nd dimension?**

---

```
size(rand(10,1))
```

gives:

```
ans =

   10    1
```

---

```
size(rand(10,1,1))
```

also gives:

```
ans =

   10    1
```

Is that because MATLAB is optimized for linear algebra? So, is it simply a convention?

Comment: By definition, MATLAB arrays always have at least two dimensions. This is by design. Originally, everything was 2D. At some point they introduced higher-dimensional arrays (I think this was MATLAB 5, but am not sure). But I guess they couldn't remove the last singleton dimension to allow 1D arrays because it would break a lot of code.

Comment: Ho you're right, I've just found [this explaination](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/08/09/essence-of-indexing/): "Arrays in MATLAB are N-dimensional, with an infinite number of trailing singleton dimensions. Trailing singleton dimensions past the second are not displayed or reported on, e.g., with size. **No array has fewer than two dimensions**. Empty arrays are the logical extension of general arrays but have at least one size 0 dimension. The syntax [] denotes the empty array of size 0x0 and is treated as an exception occasionally (for backward compatibility)"

Comment: That quote should read "Arrays in MATLAB are *N*-dimensional, with *N* ∈ [2,∞)." :)